# How to bypass certain domains from Map Remote in Charles Proxy?

Tags: charles-proxy

If I'm using Map Remote with a wildcard, how can I for example not map traffic to `*.apple.com`?

Answer (score 2):

You can totally ignore from "listening" to those hosts, by adding them "Proxy" -> "Recording Settings" -> "Exclude" tab[image]

Comment: Remember to restart Charles after this